# How can I use AngularFireDatabase in Angular 13?

Tags: angular, firebase

I have a category.service.ts file in my Angular 13 project and I tried in a lots of way implement FirebaseDatabase but it is not working.
The original sample code:

```
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
 export class CategoryService {

 constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {}

getCategories() {
 return this.db.list('/categories', {
  query: {
    orderByChild: 'name'
    }
  });
 }
}
```

product-form.component.ts

```
...

export class ProductFormComponent implements OnInit {
categories$;

constructor(categoryService: CategoryService, private productService: ProductService)
   this.categories$ = categoryService.getCategories();
 }

 save(product) {
  this.productService.create(product);
  }

 ngOnInit() {
}
```

My question is about that how can I use Angular Fire Database in Angular 13.3.0?
In my package.json the versions:

"@angular/fire": "^7.3.0"
"firebase": "^8.10.1"

The above sample code of the CategoryService does not work because compiler says that **'Module '"angularfire2/database"' has no exported member 'AngularFireDatabase'.ts(2305)'**

How can I populate this category list and further going: how can I save a product in the above mentioned version of firebase?

Comment: Can you please include your `app.module.ts` code in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I noticed, you are trying to import `AngularFireDatabase` from `angularfire2/database` but according to the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md) it should be the following:

```js
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/compat/database';
```

And according to the same [page](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md), you can push an object to your list in this way:

```js
 this.db.list('categories').push({SOME_OBJECT});  // e.g. {name: 'mark', age: '69'}
```

However, since you have not included your code for your module in your question, for my answer I am assuming that Firebase is initialized properly.

Comment: Thank you, ilpianoforte! Your recommended solution works fine!